# How to create multiple groups in a regex?

Tags: java, regex

From the string I need a group of source i.e before `TO` and target i.e after `TO`. With that I need sub group from source i.e `(3:8)` in a single regex pattern.

```
MOVE A (3:8) TO B.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to guess what might be desired here, I'd say maybe an expression similar to:

```
([^(]+(\(.+?\)))\s*TO\s*(.*)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H3j6C4/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "([^(]+(\\(.+?\\)))\\s*TO\\s*(.*)";
final String string = "MOVE A (3:8) TO B\n";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```